# MYSQL LEFT join with 'LIKE'

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-like

I am trying to join two tables. The issue is one of the tables actually has a comma-separated list inside the cell. I need to join on the 'csv cell.'  Using my salad based example I want *bacon* to join with *bacon,turkey* and give me a *cobb_salad*

```
   SELECT tbl_a.item, tbl_b.item, tbl_b.salad 
     FROM tbl_a
LEFT JOIN tbl_b
       ON  tbl_a.item LIKE CONCAT('%', tbl_b.item, '%')
```

I tried the example above and a few other varations.  I realize this is not going to be an efficent query. The issue is that the underlying dataset predates me. Luckily I only need to run the query once.

```
Expected Result
+--------+------------+
| item   |   salad    |
+--------+------------|
|  ham   | chef_salad |
| bacon  | cobb_salad |
| turkey | cobb_salad |
+---------------------+


tbl_a 
+------+
| item |
+------+
|bacon | 
| ham  | 
|turkey|
+------+  

tbl_b
+--------------+------------+
|     item     |  salad     |
+--------------+------------+
| ham          | chef_salad |
| bacon,turkey | cobb_salad |
+--------------|------------+
```

Comment: Can you format your question? I don't understand what's being asked here?

Comment: Visit [Editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to know how to format your question.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457471/mysql-in-list-only-validates-first-id-in-list-maybe-a-blob-issue/5457653).

Comment: Sorry about that, hit submit before I worked out the formatting.. corrected it above to make clear..

Comment: Please don't vote down the question. He is just a newbie on SO.

Comment: Just as a side-note, this is a very strange way of storing data in a database. For this application, you would generally have 3 tables: A table of ingredients, a table of dishes, and a table while links one to many ingredients to a dish.

Comment: I 100% agree....  The original table is table-b, it is part of some legacy system that has been around 15 years and can only store flat files  The flat files are then imported in to mysql by a process that I dont have access to.  They basicly hacked a large text field in table-b to fake a one-to-many relationship with table-a.   Since I dont own the flat file or the database I am trying to work with what i got.  If designing from scratch I certainly wouldn't do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NOTICE:

I show in your db, there are many `space characters` in your tables.
Please try to trim it before inserting into your db.
Ex:
**From:**
`ham` => `[space]ham[space]`
**To:**
`ham` => `[no-space]ham[no-space]`
Hope you understand what I said.

---

You can try:
It works for me:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> SELECT tbl_a.item as item_a, tbl_b.item as item_b, tbl_b.salad
    -> FROM tbl_a LEFT JOIN tbl_b 
    -> ON FIND_IN_SET(tbl_a.item, tbl_b.item);
+--------+--------------+------------+
| item_a | item_b       | salad      |
+--------+--------------+------------+
| bacon  | bacon,turkey | cobb_salad |
| ham    | ham          | chef_salad |
+--------+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### UPDATE:

Here is my tables:

```
mysql> select * from tbl_a;
+-------+
| item  |
+-------+
| bacon |
| ham   |
+-------+
```

AND

```
mysql> select * from tbl_b;
+--------------+------------+
| item         | salad      |
+--------------+------------+
| bacon,turkey | cobb_salad |
| ham          | chef_salad |
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: This works perfectly.. I was looking at FIND_IN_SET in the 
[MYSQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but once I saw it returning a the position of a string in a substring I didnt think it could solve my problem.  Thanks..

Comment: @personalt: Welcome you to SO. This is perfect site. You just write nice question and the answer will come.